# Maven Dependencies Not Imported in IntelliJ 14.1.4

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

While doing a test project, i added below dependency at a later stage,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But if i try to import `@RunWith`, it says invalid name.

See the picture below,

[image]

**What i have tried?**

1 - Changing Maven settings to "Auto-Import".

2 - Updated "Repositories" in maven settings.

3 - Selected "ReImport" in the maven options.

I am very new to this IDE. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added this dependency to the `test` scope. You must create a test module and use it there. Under `src` directory create `test/java` directory and put there your packages with tests.

Right click on the `src` directory and go to `New -> Directory`, then type `test/java`, next right click on the created `java` directory and on the most bottom part you should see `Mark Directory As`, choose `Test Sources Root`

Comment: How can i do that? I am using this IDE first time.

Comment: Did that. It doesn't show the error. Also its not importing anything. `AutoComplete` doesnot seem to work. Is that how it should be?

Comment: @Rajkishan`AutoComplete` feature should work properly, please check my  suggestions once again and let me know how it works.

Comment: `AutoComplete` works now. But auto import or any error correction does not work. Suppose, if i miss a `bracket` or `semicolon` or and spelling mistakes. And i had to add the imports myself.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I marked it as `Resources Root` previously. Marking it as `Test Resources Root` solved it. Thank you.